# I need an algorithm that count the number of words in column M that start with letters "a" and "A" in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here I have  code that only counts the number of words and I dont know what to do to make it count the words that start with letter "A" and "a" in column M

```
Sub CountWords()
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xRgEach As Range
    Dim xAddress As String       
    Dim xRgVal As String
    Dim xRgNum As Long
    Dim xNum As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Introduceti diapazonul:", "Selectare", xAddress, , , , , 8)

    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(xRg) = xRg.Count Then
        MsgBox "Numarul de cuvinte este: 0", vbInformation, ""
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each xRgEach In xRg
        xRgVal = xRgEach.Value
        xRgVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(xRgVal)
        If xRgEach.Value <> "" Then
            xNum = Len(xRgVal) - Len(Replace(xRgVal, " ", "")) + 1
            xRgNum = xRgNum + xNum
        End If
    Next xRgEach

    MsgBox "Numarul de cuvinte: " & Format(xRgNum, "#,##0"), vbOKOnly, "Raspuns"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Something along the lines of `=COUNTIF(M:M,"a*")` which will count upper- and lowercase. If you must use `VBA` you could still apply it through `WorksheetFunction`

Comment: @JvdV I think he needs it to count individual words within a cell that begin with a, for example `Any and all words` in a single cell would get counted as 3.  Doing a CountIf would only count that as one.

Comment: @tigeravatar, it appears so looking at the code. You are correct =). I did not take the time to go through the code like you did.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that each cell contains a **single** word, use:

```
Sub ACount()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, Kount As Long
    Dim ch As String
    Kount = 0
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        ch = Left(Cells(i, "M").Value, 1)
        If ch = "a" Or ch = "A" Then Kount = Kount + 1
    Next i
    MsgBox Kount
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

If the cells can contain **more than one** word (*separated by spaces*), the use:

```
Sub ACount()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, Kount As Long
    Dim ch As String
    Kount = 0
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        arr = Split(Cells(i, "M").Value, " ")
        For Each A In arr
            ch = Left(A, 1)
            If ch = "a" Or ch = "A" Then Kount = Kount + 1
        Next A
    Next i
    MsgBox Kount
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative via arrays including found word list display**

It might be helpful to include a **list of all valid words** to the demanded count result.

Just to demonstrate a similar approach as Gary, but using **arrays** instead of a range loop, 
I condensed the main procedure to three steps using a help function for step `[1]`:

- `[1]` get data and provide for a sufficient wrds array by calling a help function `getData()`
- `[2]` count & collect valid words in a loop through all words,
- `[3]` display count `cnt` (or: `UBound(wrds)` *plus* list of valid words (►1-based 1-dim array`wrds`)

Furthermore it's possible to analyze single words as well as word groups separated by spaces.
[image]

```
Sub ACount2()
    Const SEARCHLETTER As String = "a"                  ' << change to any wanted search letter
    '[1] get data and provide for sufficient wrds array
    Dim allWrds, wrds: allWrds = getData(Sheet1, wrds)  ' << change Sheet1 to your sheet's Code(Name)

    '[2] count & collect valid words
    Dim i As Long, letter As String, cnt As Long
    For i = LBound(allWrds) To UBound(allWrds)           ' loop through original words
        letter = LCase(Left(allWrds(i), 1))              ' compare with search letter (lower case)
        If letter = SEARCHLETTER Then cnt = cnt + 1: wrds(cnt) = allWrds(i)
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve wrds(1 To cnt)

    '[3] display count plus list of valid words
    MsgBox cnt & " words starting with {A|a}:" & _
           vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           Join(wrds, ", "), vbInformation
End Sub
```

**Help function `getData()` called by above procedure**

```
Function getData(sht As Worksheet, wrds, Optional ByVal col = "M", Optional ByVal StartRow As Long = 2)
'Purpose: get column data of a given worksheet and return to a "flat" array; provide for a sufficient wrds array
    'a) get 2-dim data (starting in cell M2 by default) and transpose to 1-dim "flat" array
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim data: data = Split(Join(Application.Transpose(sht.Range(col & StartRow & ":" & col & lastRow)), " "), " ")
    'b) provide for maximum elements in found words in calling procedure (implicit ByRef!)
    ReDim wrds(1 To UBound(data))
    'c) return 1-based "flat" 1-dim data array
    getData = data
End Function
```

Comment: For a large set of cells, your method would be faster.